# Display -> System Settings no icons are available

Tags: display

When I go to Displays in Ubuntu 13.10 I get this:

[image]

Can you help me please ?

Regards.

Comment: What are the results of running the command: `lspci -nn | grep VGA`?

Comment: ~$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] [1002:6840] (rev ff)